# CCParticleSystemQuad not working in version 3.0 of cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm trying to port a game made using Cocos2d-X version 2, to the new version 3.0.
I found that CCParticleSystemQuad seems to be deprecated.

What can I use instead?

This is how I've been using it:

class ParticleCollision : public CCParticleSystemQuad

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The 'CC' prefix is deprecated for most classes. So CCParticleSystemQuad is now just ParticleSystemQuad, for example.

ParticleSystemQuad is not deprecated AFAIK. It's not in the deprecated list for the 3.1 rc0.

Answer (score 1):

`CCParticleSystemQuad` was deprecated but v3.0, 3.1 implements a new Physics Engine

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.1rc0/db/dd9/classcocos2d_1_1_particle_system.html

It seems valid to me: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.1rc0/d5/d59/classcocos2d_1_1_particle_system_quad.html

The Release Notes mention it: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v3/docs/RELEASE_NOTES.md

Answer (score 0):

It is not the 'CC' Prefix. Please note that, `CCParticleSystemQuad` is now changed to `CCParticleSystem`. 
Please refer this for details: [Cocos2D Forum CCParticleSystemQuad Missing?](http://forum.spritebuilder.com/t/ccparticlesystemquad-missing/12713/2)